# How to run a search engine script in Python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am learning how to do webscraping, crawlers etc. and I came across this [repo](https://github.com/logicx24/Text-Search-Engine). I understand how the code works, what the input and outputs should be, but how do I run it in a terminal on Windows? How do I call the respective .txt files and test the search engine?

I saw that someone else asked that and the creator showed them this link [here](http://aakashjapi.com/fuckin-search-engines-how-do-they-work/). But it still doesn't explain how to actually apply it to files.

Comment: This is quite broad, and possibly off-topic. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

The author of logicx24 has hard coded the target text files in querytexts.py.  See line 122 which reads:

q = Query(['pg135.txt', 'pg76.txt', 'pg5200.txt'])

The list input to Query are all references to files that exist in the corpus directory.  Try changing that to include a different file in their corpus directory.  Better yet, add a new target text file of your own and use that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using text files? I don't get it. Either way, you could just use Python itself to do that. Use the `selenium` library for Python. There's a tutorial to installing this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc&t=2s). Once that's done, just use this code if you're using Google:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gLFyf.gsfi")
time.sleep(5)
search.send_keys("Desired Input Text Goes Here")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Don't worry if it takes a while to load. It usually does that. If you want to reduce the amount of time it takes, use a lower number for the parameter on line 8 (`time.sleep(5)`). Assuming you've gone ahead and learned a bit more about Selenium, there isn't really much else to talk about apart from one thing. That is, line 7 (`search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gLFyf.gsfi"`). Assuming you've learned advanced CSS selectors already (if you have literally no experience in web development, specifically HTML and CSS, you can just copy-paste the code), the `.gLFyf.gsfi` is simply the CSS selector for the search bar in Google. You can find the selector for the search bar in any  engine by just looking through the source code using `Ctrl + Shift + I` on Windows. You can use any other Selenium element selector for this as long as it works. Make sure to also change the URL on line 6 (`driver.get("https://www.google.com")`) to match that of your search engine if you're not using Google.

Sorry if this seemed a bit vague or strange. If you don't really care, feel free to download Selenium, copy-paste the code, and move on. Otherwise, I suggest also learning Selenium and HTML/CSS if you haven't already.